# Jquery slider value not zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see the code live here: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/50/

My HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input id="sliderValue" />
<div id="boksTimer"></div>
```

My JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#slider").slider({value:'',min: 0,max: 150,step: 0.5, range: 'min',
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).html( ui.value + ' timer');
        $('#sliderValue').val(ui.value);
    }
});

    var thumb = $($('#slider').children('.ui-slider-handle'));   
    setLabelPosition();    

    $('#slider').bind('slide', function () {        
        $('#boksTimer').html(((($('#slider').slider('value')) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + 'min pr. dag');
        setLabelPosition();
    });

        function setLabelPosition() {
        var label = $('#boksTimer');
        label.css('top', '20px');
        label.css('left', thumb.offset().left - (label.width() - thumb.width())/ 2);        
    }

});
```

Why is the value of the boksTimer 1min pr. day when the slider is at 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ui.value to get slider value on slide event function:

```js
$('#slider').bind('slide', function (event, ui) {   
    $('#boksTimer').html((((ui.value) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + 'min pr. dag');
    setLabelPosition();
});
```